# What URI should I expect HTTP DELETEs at?

Tags: api, rest, design-consideration

This is more of a conceptual integrity question for something that's been bothering me.

HTTP's DELETE method is supposed to be idempotent, and REST's URIs are supposed to actually represent things. But it seems to be only defined in the *reverse* direction: each resource must have one URI, but a given URI doesn't seem to need a resource. More charitably I guess URIs could be defined to point at empty/null resources.

The only time this seems actually relevant is in a DELETE request. Where is the best place to put it? `example.com/users/` with the content identifying the resource to be deleted, or is `example.com/users/USERNAME` better?

Content in DELETE seems fine in HTTP and REST. (Conceptually: according to other SO questions various frameworks will silently drop content from DELETE requests before you can process it.)

So here's my thinking: every example seems to use the latter scheme--where you're deleting a resource at *its* URI, not deleting a resource from its *parent collection* URI--but the resource should stop existing after a successful DELETE. In which case the URI should fail loudly, imho. But that would negate the idempotence of DELETE, leading me to think that DELETE should operate on collections, with the content specifying the actual resource to be deleted.

Obviously everybody just does the thing that I don't like and I should probably go along with it for the sanity of my users, but is there anywhere where this is clearly spelled out, or obvious things that I'm missing that make me wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the HTTP standard "The DELETE method requests that the origin server delete the resource identified by the Request-URI." - there's nothing about any sort of request body.

> In which case the URI should fail loudly, imho. But that would negate the idempotence of DELETE

Just return a 404. The point of idempotence is, submitting the same DELETE request twice doesn't cause the server state to end up any different from having submitted it once. Failing doesn't cause a problem for that (unless the server shuts down or something)

Answer (score 1):

A `DELETE` request should only apply to the URI of the resource you would like deleted. For deleting something via a collection, a `POST` or `PUT` to that collection would be more appropriate.

You can implement a response to the `DELETE` request by checking for the resource and deleting it if it exists and return 2xx, otherwise just return 2xx (e.g., in case duplicate requests were sent). The point of making the method idempotent is that it won't "fail loudly"—it isn't considered a failure at all. Just like how `PUT` doesn't differentiate between "create" and "update".

Comment: I agree about `POST` or `PUT` to delete from a collection, but I'm not sure how I feel about returning 2xx instead of 404 in the case of an object not existing. Either way the status of the server doesn't change, but I think a client should be willing to distinguish between 2xx and 404, if it feels like it.